# Gaussian filter in fourier domain

Tags: matlab, fft, gaussian

I try to apply an Gaussian filter in Fourier domain with matlab, the result is blurred but the output image is messy like a puzzle, I don't know why!

```
img='src.pgm';
scale=10;

I=imread(img);
S=size(I);
TF_I=zeros([S(1) S(2)]);

TF_I= fft2(I);

mask = fspecial('gaussian',S(1),scale);

TF_mask=fft2(mask);

TF_out = TF_I.*TF_mask;

img_out=ifft2(TF_out);

img_out=uint8(img_out);

imshow(img_out);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
TF_mask=fft2(ifftshift(mask));
```

The DFT (what `fft` computes) assumes the origin is at the top-left pixel. `mask` has the origin in the middle of the image. `ifftshift` shifts the origin to the top-left pixel.